# Power Query - How to create a perpetual calendar with holidays

Tags: powerbi, calendar, powerquery

I would like to create a perpetual calendar in Power BI (Power Query) with the holidays. The thing is, I live in Canada and Easter and Victoria Day are quite complicated to integrate in this kind of calendar.

For the perpetual calendar, I used [this technique (you can find the code on this website)](https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/extended-date-table-power-query-m-function/6390), which is very effective. It's "simply" a function to which you tell that you want a calendar from this date to this date and it generates everything you want and probably more. However, the calendar doesn't know which day is a holiday. So you need to have another request in Power BI with all the holidays for that period. Then you tell the calendar to use this holiday request as a reference point and then it will know which day is a holiday.

This is where it gets very complicated. Some holidays are based on a specific date, some are based on a specific day and others vary a lot.

- Based on a specific date : New Year's Day, January 1st ; Saint-Jean-Baptiste Day, June 24 ; Canada Day, July 1st ; National Day for Thruth and Reconciliation, September 30 ; Remembrance Day, November 11 ; Christmas Day, December 25 ; Boxing Day, December 26.
- Based on a specific day : Labour day, first Monday of September ; Thanksgiving, second Monday of October.
- Those that vary a lot : Good Friday, Friday before Easter ; [Easter, first Sunday after the Paschal full moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_full_moon#Paschal_full_moon) ; Easter Monday, Monday after Easter ; Victoria Day, last Monday preceding May 25.
- Finally, some holidays happen only once to commemorate specific events like the death of the Queen on September 19, 2022.

I would like to create a function to which I indicate that I want all holiday for a specific period and it generates everything by itself. Then I could tell my calendar function to use it as a reference to know which day is a holiday. It would also be great if I could add some new holiday here and there for specific events like the death of the Queen.

For holidays like New Year's Day, Canada Day and Thanksgiving, I used [this tutorial](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/perpetual-holiday-calendar-potw-12-power-query-solution/), but it's incomplete. Also, it doesn’t explain how to integrate holidays like Easter or Victoria Day. So this is where I'm stuck right now.

I know it's complicated but if someone can help me, it would be awesome.

Comment: Please show your code and the problem you're facing.

Comment: We tend to be good at helping people implement their idea when they have coding problems.  Not so good at helping with methodologies for determining when Canadian holidays falls.  Perhaps if you come up with the methodology we can help with the coding

Comment: Do you need a perpetual calendar? You can do it a lot easier with two tables, your normal calendar and the holiday one, you will then have to combine them to get the columns with 'Is Holiday' or whatever logic you need. I would use the https://canada-holidays.ca/api to get the holiday data, you can join the items together.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon !Your suggestion is much simpler and it will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon suggest, I think it will be a lot easier to use the canada-holidays.ca/api.

I'm having issues with this API though. If I want multiple years in a single request, I need to create a request for each year and then append them. I'm trying to find a way to only have a single request but I'm struggling with this as well.

As soon as I find a solution, I'll update this post.

EDIT

Someone help me with that on another post. You can find the solution [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74535741/power-query-how-to-integrate-multiple-sources-and-append-them-in-one-request)!